# Obtengo error al usar blockinput

Tags: c++

Hola estoy modificando una pequeña aplicación en c++ que me permita tomar control de mi ratón y mi teclado, el código es el siguiente:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibraryW (L"user32.dll");
    if (hDLL == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to load user32.dll, error code %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }


    typedef BOOL (WINAPI *BLOCKINPUT)(BOOL);
    BLOCKINPUT pBlockInput;
    pBlockInput = (BLOCKINPUT)GetProcAddress (hDLL, "BlockInput");
    if (pBlockInput == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to import BlockInput, error code %d\n", GetLastError());
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        BOOL res = pBlockInput (TRUE);
        if (!res) {
           fprintf (stderr, "BlockInput failed, error code %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
        Sleep (20);
    }



    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    _getch();
}
```

El problema esque se me va directamente al if ya que parece ser que la variable res siempre es falsa entonces no consigo hacer lo que estoy intentando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que basicamente con el blockinput durante un tiempo nadie pueda usar mi teclado y ratón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error **5** es:

> ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

La documentación de `BlockInput( )` no indica nada al respecto. Sin embargo, desde *Windows Vista* en adelante, el uso de la función `BlockInput` **necesita** del privilegio de administrador.

Así que la solución mas sencilla es ejecutar tu programa como **Administrador**.